# Spyder: Is there any way to leave the "view background colour" in the variable explorer unchecked by default?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, spyder

For personal preference, I prefer viewing my dataframes without the colouring scheme:

[image: variable explorer]

There is an option to untick the 'background colour' option, but every time I open up another numpy/pandas array it's ticked again by default.

Is there anything in the settings to turn off "background colour" in the variable explorer by DEFAULT.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, there isn't, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Could I just ask two follow up questions:                                                                                                    1. What do the colours in the variable explorer represent? What is their purpose?                               2. Are there any plans to update spyder in the future to have an option to remove the colours by default?

Comment: 1. They are a heatmap, where the highest values are colored blueish and the lowest are pinkish; and 2. No, there are no plans because no one else has requested it.